# Which version of C# should I learn for ArcObjects with .NET?

Tags: arcobjects, c#

I'm wanting to pick up ArcObjects and have decided on C# over VB as my language. I know that arcpy uses python version 2.7. If I had started learning python 3.2 to learn arcpy I'm sure I would have had issues. I don't want to have any extra issues learning C#. Which version of C# should I learn?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ESRI recommends to use the Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 Service Pack 1 for version 10 and higher:

- [ArcObjects SDK System Requirements for 10.1](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/system-requirements/10.1/index.html#//01510000006n000000)
- [ArcObjects SDK System Requirements for 10.2](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/system-requirements/10.2/index.html#//01510000006n000000)

So as you can see in this post [What are the correct version numbers for C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247621/what-are-the-correct-version-numbers-for-c) you should learn C# 3.0.

Answer (score 2):

They also have instructions for using .NET 4.0 or 4.5 if you wish to take advantage of the new language features:

[.NET 4.0 and 4.5 support for ArcGIS 10.2 Desktop and Engine developers](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//000100000nzv000000)

The only change you need to make is to edit ArcMap.exe.config (or the relevant .exe.config for the application you are extending) and changing:

```
<startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
</startup>
```

to:

```
<startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0.30319"/>
</startup>
```

This causes ArcMap to load the v4 runtime, which directly supports .NET 4.0 and 4.5 assemblies and also allows the v2 runtime to load side-by-side for .NET 3.5 and earlier assemblies.

However, as Katah says, ESRI recommend using .NET 3.5 for add-ins. At least one reason for this is that add-ins do not require a setup program to install them and so there is not necessarily a way to verify that .NET 4 or 4.5 is installed and that ArcMap is configured to use it when distributing your add-in.